# ¿Como pasar variables de javascript hacia ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lo que quiero conseguir es que cuando un usuario le de clic en mi menú que esta en una parte de mi pagina este mismo aparezca pero en otra parte de mi pagina web.

Función de mi título del menu

```
<div id="TituloMenu" >
    <%= image_tag "menu2.png" , :class=>"imagenM2" , :id=>"img" , :onclick=>"menu(1)"%>
    Titulo del Menu
</div>
```

Aquí aparece mi menu

```
<%= yield %>
```

Todo esto esta dentro de mi archivo application.html.erb, lo que me gustaría es pasar un valor de application.html.erb hacia yield, que en dado caso seria quien tiene el contenido de la pagina web

explicación de como debería funcionar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> Actualizacion

---

Todo se encuentra en un mismo archivo como inicial, que seria el de application.html.erb, el titulo, el pie de pagina y el contenido que es el yield, usa el patrón de diseño template, así que lo que quiero es llegar del div del titulo al div del yield que por defecto viene así al crear por consola, me gustaría pasar los parámetros entre ambos divs a través de javascript y la función de menu(1) manda un valor al darse clic a dicha función para que dependiendo si es uno o cero muestre u oculte el div del menú que se encuentra dentro de yield

Comment: Está confusa tu pregunta, aparte que siento que no has puesto el código relevante para responderte. ¿donde está ubicado ese `yield`?¿Que hace esa función `menu(1)`?¿Por que quieres mandar variables js a rails? La única forma de hacer eso es a través de un request al servidor y parece que lo que necesitas tiene que ver solamente con js. ¿Has evaluado usar un framework css responsive como bootstrap? Creo que eso podría ser lo que necesitas, aunque no me queda claro.

Comment: ya hice cambios, por si gustas checarlos

Comment: primero que todo creo que necesitas mayor conocimiento de MVC, rails y javascript o jquery. Segundo creo que, si solo necesitas pasar información en la misma pagina (vista, view, HTML o como quieras llamarlo), solo necesitas javascript ( o jquery que te facilitará más la area). con jquery puedes utilizar http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: @David disculpa mi ignorancia, pero que valor es el que quieres pasar a javascript?

Comment: @sioesi lo que me gustaria pasar como valor seria por el momento un numero (int)

Answer (score 1):

puedes enviar los datos a través de un hidden para poder manipularlo en el controlador

```
<%=f.hidden_field :datos, :id => "datos", :value => "" %>
```

cambia el valor del hidden en el momento que desees con jquery

```
$("datos").attr("value", "nuevo valor");
```

y obtienes el valor en el controlador después del submit

```
@datos = params[:form]["datos"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
function readData() {
    var js_to_rails = 81; //Asignación del valor a la variable
    if (js_to_rails) {
        window.open("localhost:3000//tasks/new?js_to_rails="+js_to_rails,"_self")
    }
}
```

**app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb**

```
  # GET /tasks/new
  def new
    #byebug #para visualizar el valor que tiene params
    @in_rails = params[:js_to_rails]   #Recepción de la variable, y se asigna a una variable de instancia 
    @task = Task.new
  end
```

**app/views/tasks/new.html.erb**

```
<h1>New Task</h1>

<%# Visualizamos el valor enviado desde javascript %>
<%="valor en la vista: " + @in_rails %>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', tasks_path %>
```

Donde se puede visualizar el valor en la vista `/new`

[image: Visualizacion del valor enviado desde js]

Answer (score 0):

Yo te diría que no es necesario pasar el parámetro.  Ten en cuenta que al momento de que la página se carga por completo, se forma una sola página con todo el contenido.  Rails se encarga de construir la página completa y con lo que se construya trabajará javascript.

La función que reacciona al click del menú debe existir en el contexto de la página, de preferencia en un archivo separado.  En yield utiliza nombres predefinidos para que puedas manipularlos con certeza y no genere error.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo mejor seria utilizar AJAX, por ejemplo... si quiero enviar datos a mi controlador al método "create":

```
$("#guardar").click(function(){
                // alert("The button was clicked.");
                var campo = document.getElementById('id_campo').value;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/modelo/create",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                            "campo":campo
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            }
```